# Что такое спецификация и реализация для Java?

Tags: java, openjdk

Смотрю вебинар и там как то прошелся по теме Java спецификация и JDK реализация. Можно ли в доходчивом языке описать со структурой что это и как они друг от друга зависит.

Comment: За что минусы то???

Comment: Полагаю, что за крайне скупое описание вопроса и отсутствие контекста. Непонятно что за вебинар и что в нем имели ввиду. Цитата и подробности улучшили бы вопрос.

Comment: @defaultlocale  я не думаю что спецификация ява это вещь динамическая и каким либо боком зависит от контекста Вебинара.Конкретный вопрос требующий конкретный ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добрый день, чтобы разобраться что такое "jdk реализация" вам нужно будет понять, что такое JDK и JVM, собственно сейчас об этом:

JDK(Java Development Kit) является основным компонентом среды Java и предоставляет все инструменты, исполняемые и бинарные файлы, которые нужны для компиляции, отладки и выполнения программы на Java.

JVM(Java Virtual Machine) является сердцем языка программирования Java. Когда мы запускаем программу, JVM несет ответственность за преобразование байт-кода в машинный код. JVM также зависит от платформы и предоставляет основные функции, такие как управления памятью Java, сборкой мусора, и т.д.

А вот теперь пришло время поговорить о "jdk реализация", а если по правильному, то JRE(Java Runtime Environment). Она является реализацией JVM, которая предоставляет платформу для выполнения Java-программ. JRE состоит из виртуальной машины Java, бинарных файлов и других классов. JRE не содержит инструменты для разработки (компилятор Java, отладчик и т.д). Если вы хотите запустить любую Java программу, вы должны установить JRE.

По поводу спецификации вот ссылка https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf Если не знаете, что такое спецификация в общем, то это сухое описание продукта или подхода выполнения каких-либо действий. ТТХ если хотите.